# How integrate caffeine with Spring 3.1?

Tags: java, spring, spring-cache, caffeine

There are a lot of example about caffeine and Spring 4+ or Spring boot integration. But how integrate caffeine with Spring **3.1** and Spring cache (**not** JCache)?

Comment: Which java version are you using?

Comment: probably not at all / or you need to write the entire spring integration yourself.

Comment: It seems 3.1 is old enough to not include Guava's cache either, which would be a strategy through the adapter. The integration is [really simple](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/tree/4.3.x/spring-context-support/src/main/java/org/springframework/cache/caffeine), so you should be able to backport it.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a support for Caffeine in Spring 3.1. You may want to consider upgrading to a more recent Spring Framework version (3.1 is EOL). Caffeine support is available as of 4.3.